# Initial Image Size of dynamic plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, dynamic

I have a dynamic plot. I want to set an initial image size and then be able to resize it by dragging with the mouse. When the image is updated, I want to maintain the "dragged" size.

A naive attempt with a simplified example:

```
Slider[Dynamic[n], {0, 5}]
Dynamic[Plot[n (x - n)^2, {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Large]]
```

It sets ImageSize->Large. I can resize the plot by select and dragging, but as soon as I change n with the slider, the plot is evaluated and the size reverts to Large.

So how can I apply setting ImageSize->Large only as an initial condition and keep the "dragged" size as n changes?

Thanks in advance for your expert help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
In order to set initial values in a dynamical system one has to use DynamicModule.

Anyway, if you now change slightly your code in the following way:

```
Slider[Dynamic[n], {0, 5}]
DynamicModule[{p1 = 200}, 
Dynamic[Plot[n (x - n)^2, {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Dynamic[p1]]]]
```

the image should remember its size.

Comment: So it seems you can drop the ImageSizeCache rule as far as I can tell, since Mathematica will put it in automatically. I played a little and found that Mathematica automatically updates p1 as I resize the plot window with the mouse. I never would have thought of that!

Comment: @Michael Yup, this makes the code much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[n (x - n)^2, {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> $size], {n, 0, 
      1}, {{$size, 550}, 100, 1000}]
```

On my system, Large ~ 550, so I chose that as the starting point.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not looking for a second slider. I want to be able to use select and drag with the mouse to resize.

Comment: I'm still unclear.  Ignoring my `$size` slider for a moment, you can click & drag the plot and changing the value of `n` won't reset the size.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes! Problem now solved.

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
Slider[Dynamic[n, (imgs = Automatic; n = #) &], {0, 5}]
```

[image]

```
imgs = 400;
Dynamic[Plot[n (x - n)^2, {x, 0, 5},
  ImageSize -> imgs]]
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Changing n reverts the plot to some small size.

Comment: You can change some code running order. I have changed like over that...don't you want to do that...